# One column as parameter both having and where (excluding)

Tags: sql, firebird

I have such two queries:

First:

```
select p.prodid, p.name, max(b.ldate) as lastsale 
from prod p, buy b 
where p.id = b.idprod and b.id<>0  and b.wskus=0 and b.bufor=0
group by p.prodid, p.name
HAVING sum(b.curNo)=0
order by p.name asc
```

Second

```
select p.prodid, p.name, min(b.buydate) as oldest_buy 
from prod p, buy b         
where p.id = b.idprod and b.id<>0  and b.wskus=0 and b.bufor=0 and b.curNo>0
group by p.prodid, p.name
order by p.name asc
```

How can I make JOIN for them to have as a result columns:

```
| p.prodid | p.name | lastsale | oldest_buy |
| 1        | ex1    | 1.1.18   | NULL       |
| 2        | ex2    | NULL     | 1.1.18     |
```

as `HAVING sum(b.curNo)=0` from first query is exclusive to `WHERE` parameter from second query `b.curNo>0` I have problem how to make this work.

Comment: Is "and" missing in the 2nd query ( "b.bufor=0 b.curNo>0")?

Comment: Yes i missed it while writing this question. Updated above

Comment: Is b.curNo always >= 0 (never negative or null)?

Comment: Yes it starts as >0 and drops at last to =0

Comment: If a prodid is in query1, it won't be in query2.  The result rows would either have a lastsale or oldest_buy but not both.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. thats how it works

Comment: @kc2018 lastsale means prodid that is out of stock and when last sale of it was made, oldest_buy is the oldest bought prodid That in on stock

Comment: @Nysander Then I'm guessing you meant `p.curNo`?  You ***really*** should include example data do make it clearer *as well as* making it possible to spot typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your input data it's hard to tell, but it's possible this will work for you...

```
SELECT
  p.prodid,
  p.name,
  MIN(CASE WHEN b.curNo > 0 THEN b.buydate END)     AS oldest_buy,   -- MIN(buydate) WHERE curno>0
  CASE WHEN SUM(b.curNo) = 0 THEN MAX(b.ldate) END  AS lastsale      -- MAX(ldate) HAVING SUM(curNo) = 0
FROM
  prod p
INNER JOIN   -- Don't use "," use "JOIN"s, the standard for about 25 years...
  buy b
    ON p.id = b.idprod
WHERE
      b.id    <> 0
  AND b.wskus  = 0
  AND b.bufor  = 0
GROUP BY
  p.prodid,
  p.name
ORDER BY
  p.name  ASC
```

It's possible that moving the `b.curNo > 0` or the `SUM(b.curNo) = 0` in to the `CASE` statements will give extra rows, depending on the behavior of your data.  It's impossible to tell without more details or example data.

The values in the two calculations will be okay, but I can't speak for the number of rows.

To be more explicit about it you could do...

```
SELECT
  p.prodid,
  p.name,
  CASE WHEN MAX(b.curNo) > 0 THEN MIN(CASE WHEN b.curNo > 0 THEN b.buydate END) END    AS oldest_buy,
  CASE WHEN SUM(b.curNo) = 0 THEN MAX(b.ldate)                                  END   AS lastsale
FROM
  prod p
INNER JOIN   -- Don't use "," use "JOIN"s, the standard for about 25 years...
  buy b
    ON p.id = b.idprod
WHERE
      b.id    <> 0
  AND b.wskus  = 0
  AND b.bufor  = 0
GROUP BY
  p.prodid,
  p.name
HAVING
     SUM(b.curNo) = 0
  OR MAX(b.curNo) > 0
ORDER BY
  p.name  ASC
```

Another possibility *(Again because you didn't give example data)* is to aggregate then join.

This is based on the notion that you mean `p.curNo` rather than `b.curNo`...

```
SELECT
  p.prodid,
  p.name,
  CASE p.curNo > 0 THEN b.oldest_buy END   AS oldest_buy,
  CASE p.curNo = 0 THEN b.last_sale  END   AS lastsale
FROM
  prod p
INNER JOIN   -- Don't use "," use "JOIN"s, the standard for about 25 years...
(
  SELECT
     idprod,
     MIN(buydate)    AS oldest_buy,
     MAX(ldate)      AS last_sale
  FROM
     buy
  WHERE
        b.id    <> 0
    AND b.wskus  = 0
    AND b.bufor  = 0
)
  b
    ON p.id = b.idprod
ORDER BY
  p.name  ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first example works flawlessly. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @nysander But the last solution is probably better, if it applies *(you never did clarify if it should have been `p.curNo`)*.  Don't just settle for the first thing that works...

Comment: b.curNo is valid. There is no such column as p.curNo

Comment: And sum(b.curNo)=0 is also important factor

Comment: You said b.curNo starts positive then tends to zero. Which means that the sum(b.curNo) will always be positive...  Something you're saying doesn't add up.

Comment: I buy prodid many times. I need to Know oldest delivery which is not sold out. This is one parameter >0. But for sold out prodid when there is 0 on stock i need to Know when prodid was sold for the last time. I hope this clarifies why your first example works best.

Answer (score 0):

Put the first query in a subquery before union all. Try this:

```
select 
t.prodid, t.name, t.lastsale, null as oldest_buy
from (select p.prodid, p.name, 
             max(b.ldate) as lastsale 
      from   prod p, buy b 
      where  p.id = b.idprod and b.id<>0  and 
             b.wskus=0 and b.bufor=0
      group by p.prodid, p.name
      HAVING sum(b.curNo)=0 ) t
union all
( select p.prodid, p.name, 
  null as lastsale, min(b.buydate) as oldest_buy 
  from prod p, buy b        
  where p.id = b.idprod and b.id<>0  and b.wskus=0 
  and b.bufor=0 and b.curNo>0
  group by p.prodid, p.name )
order by 2 asc
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer but @matbailie's answer is more readable so i choosed his.